# How to Convert UTF-16 Surrogate Decimal to UNICODE in Java

Tags: java, surrogate-pairs

I have some string data like

> &#55357 ;&#56842 ;

These are surrogate pairs in UTF 16 in decimal format.

How can I convert them to Unicode Code Points in Java, so that my client can understand the Unicode decimal html entity without the surrogate pair?

Example: `&#128522 ;`  - Get this response for the above string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already parsed the string to get the 2 numbers, just create a String from those two `char` values:

```
String s = new String(new char[] { 55357, 56842 });
System.out.println(s);
```

*Output*

To get the code point of that:

```
s.codePointAt(0) // returns 128522
```

You don't have to create a string though:

```
Character.toCodePoint((char) 55357, (char) 56842) // returns 128522
```

Comment: I'm able to get this working!! Thank you very much!!